INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME error while installing cytoscape on Linux Mint 22
I read a lot of tips to resolve this issue but no luck, nothing works for me...
My host : Linux Mint 22 Wilma based on Ubuntu 24.04
Cytoscape download : https://cytoscape.org/download.html
In a terminal I launched :
bash ./Cytoscape_3_10_2_unix.sh

It throws an error :
No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 17.0.2 and at most 17.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.

So I look at my java version :
java --version
  openjdk 21.0.4 2024-07-16
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu224.04)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.4+7-Ubuntu-1ubuntu224.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Java version is > 17 as required
When I run update-alternatives here is the result :
sudo update-alternatives --config java
  There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                         Priority   Status
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  * 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   2111      auto mode
    1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java   2111      manual mode

So I tried to set INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME :
export INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
bash ./Cytoscape_3_10_2_unix.sh

But always the same error :
No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
The version of the JVM must be at least 17.0.2 and at most 17.
Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.

I tried different syntax as this but no one works :
export INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin
export INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64

I tried to set JAVA_HOME the same way as INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME but still the same error.
I don't know what else I can check !
Thanx for your help

It clearly states that the problem is and at most 17, you cannot use JDK 21.

Do you understand what "and at most 17" means?

thanx, due to my bad english I understood "17 and above" ! I installed open-17-jdk and it works...

@talexsetrasladóaCodidacta  the message is incoherent, it asks for a minimum version higher than the maximum version...
